# pandas reset_index after groupby.value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to groupby a column and compute value counts on another column.

```py
import pandas as pd
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 
               'Amt':[20,20,20,30,30,30,30,40, 40,10, 10, 40,40,40]})
```

`dftest` looks like

```
    A  Amt
0   1   20
1   1   20
2   1   20
3   1   30
4   1   30
5   1   30
6   1   30
7   1   40
8   1   40
9   2   10
10  2   10
11  2   40
12  2   40
13  2   40
```

perform grouping

```py
grouper = dftest.groupby('A')
df_grouped = grouper['Amt'].value_counts()
```

which gives

```
   A  Amt
1  30     4
   20     3
   40     2
2  40     3
   10     2
Name: Amt, dtype: int64
```

what I want is to keep top two rows of each group.

Also, I was perplexed by an error when I tried to `reset_index`

```py
df_grouped.reset_index()
```

it gives the following error

> ValueError: cannot insert Amt, already exists

Comment: if you do `dftest.groupby('A', as_index=False)` you won't need `reset_index()`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need parameter `name` in [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), because `Series` name is same as name of one of levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
df_grouped.reset_index(name='count')
```

Another solution is [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) `Series` name:

```
print (df_grouped.rename('count').reset_index())

   A  Amt  count
0  1   30      4
1  1   20      3
2  1   40      2
3  2   40      3
4  2   10      2
```

---

More common solution instead `value_counts` is aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df_grouped1 =  dftest.groupby(['A','Amt']).size().reset_index(name='count')

print (df_grouped1)
   A  Amt  count
0  1   20      3
1  1   30      4
2  1   40      2
3  2   10      2
4  2   40      3
```

Comment: perfect!! addresses the reset index issue... is there a better way to keep top n rows by group, count ... right now after trying a few things, only possible way that i can think of is first groupby.value_counts, then subset

Comment: Maybe need  [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) - `dftest.groupby(['A','Amt']).size().nlargest(3)`

Comment: that does not do it by group, only gives overall nlargest

Comment: you can apply nlargest to groupby, so a way could be to group again against your level 0: `df_grouped.groupby(level=0).nlargest(2)`

Comment: @Boud 's solution worked on the example mentioned. I am having trouble getting it working on multi-level-index, i might post as a separate question

Comment: I think you can provide multiple levels on the level argument

Comment: "name" is depracted in newer version of pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: One can also use `dftest.groupby(['A','Amt']).size().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: `name` is a parameter of [Series.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), not `DataFrame.reset_index` (which has a parameter `names`). `groupby` produces a `Series` (not a `DataFrame`) when there's only a single non-index column

Comment: Thanks! This saved me from issues trying to send a groupby object to mysql using pd.to_sql. Kept getting errors until I reindexed.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `reset_index` altogether, `groupby.size` may be used with `as_index=False` parameter (`groupby.size` produces the same output as `value_counts` - both drop NaNs by default anyway).

```py
dftest.groupby(['A','Amt'], as_index=False).size()
```

Since pandas 1.1., `groupby.value_counts` is a redundant operation because `value_counts()` can be directly called on the dataframe and produce the same output.

```py
dftest.value_counts(['A', 'Amt']).reset_index(name='count')
```

Since pandas 1.5., `reset_index()` admits `allow_duplicates=` parameter, which may be flagged to allow duplicate column names (as in the OP):

```py
grouper = dftest.groupby('A')
grouper['Amt'].value_counts().reset_index(allow_duplicates=True)
```