# Missing indexes after groupy by & cumsum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

I want to create a lineplot showing the commuted sales per publisher per year. For this I want to group per year and per publisher before but then I have no indexes anymore.

```
sales_per_year = df.groupby(['Publisher', 'Year'], as_index=False)['Global_Sales'].cumsum()
sns.lineplot(data=sales_per_year, x='Year', y='Global_Sales', hue='Platform')
```

|  | Global_Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 82.74 |
| 1 | 40.24 |
| 2 | 35.82 |
| 3 | 33.00 |
| 4 | 31.37 |

Comment: You can reset the index, see for example [pandas reset_index after groupby.value_counts()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778686/pandas-reset-index-after-groupby-value-counts)

Comment: where is the rest of the code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning groupby result to new df, what if we add that as new column in already existing dataframe... so try this maybe;

```
df["Global_Sales_Cumsum"] = df.groupby(['Publisher', 'Year'])['Global_Sales'].cumsum()
```

Now just call df instead of sales_per_year while plotting... Hope this Helps...